# How to verify a value based on a defined decimal increment

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to verify the value of **x** based on the value of **inc** which is the allowed increment of **x** as in the following example:

```
var inc=0.01;
var x;
//valid x value examples: 1.23, 2, 0.2
//invalid x value examples: 1.234, 0.002

if (x *does not increment by* inc){
  //do some stuff like alert that x is invalid
}
```

Is there a way in javascript which will allow me to verify if x increments by a defined value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition should work:

```
if ((x / inc) % 1 == 0) {
    // number is allowed increment
}
```

Or in your case:

```
if ((x / inc) % 1 != 0) {
    // alert user
}
```

Comment: @flodorhlod Just be wary of decimal inaccuracies ex. `x = 2.4` with `inc = 0.2`